# Has double (green) protoboard benefits when using this way of soldering?

Tags: soldering, pcb-layers, protoboard, layers

I'm intending to use the same soldering 'technique' as in the picture below (just an example), by using wires and solder connections.

I am wondering if it has benefits by using the green double sided protoboard (I have quite some of them), or using the cheaper brownish (bakelite) ones like below?

The only advantages of the green ones I can find of (for this way of soldering) is that they don't small bad and they are a bit thicker.

Do I miss some more important benefits?

(I checked google but the double layer doesn't seem useful with this technique).

[image]

Comment: They look nicer and the plating is (much ?) tougher than brown perfboard (my experience).

Comment: A protoboard of this design using two layers and plated through holes would be much more robust against delamination of pads by the heat of soldering. But when you want robust protoboards, you may prefer FR4 material using laminated glas fibers. The mechanical strength is much higher than that of FR3 laminated paper. FR3 is a bit brittle.

Comment: also, the green boards often have a proper solder mask, which is better at repelling solder than plain board, which can make it easier to avoid solder bridges.

Comment: Thanks all ... it's clear now I should go for the better one (FR4). Especially since the value of the components I want to put on it will be much more (like 5-10 microcontrollers).

Comment: 5 to 10 microcontrollers *really* sound like the time you'd spend learning to use KiCAD or Eagle to layout the would save you *a lot of time* hand-soldering connections, debugging connections…

Comment: @MarcusMüller I know, however, I'm planning to make it in steps, so I cannot 'order' some PCB... also I'm sure I will make some mistake somewhere along the way (being my first project with a microcontroller).

Comment: @MichelKeijzers but if this is your first microcontroller project, you really shouldn't start with 5 to 10 microcontrollers; in fact, you probably shouldn't even start with soldering the microcontroller to a board; there's cheap evaluation boards for many (if not most) microcontrollers you could solder, and these not only contain the microcontroller, but also things like decoupling capacitors, power supplies, and typically come with pin headers so you can directly solder them onto a board like yours, if that's still necessary. What microcontroller do you have in mind?

Comment: @MarcusMuller Sorry for my bad word choice, what I meant is using 5-10 dev boards (STM32F103C8T6 minimal development boards), these are very cheap and quite powerful. And yes, these have pin headers. I will use 3 to 'start', but later add more.

Comment: @MarcusMüller (wrong @, fixed now, sorry for missing the umlaut). See the comment above.